# Icons Disappear Hovering Over TaskBar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

When I have more than 8 or 9 applications open in Windows 7, the icons of the open applications disappear when I hover over them. [This](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1077365/taskbar.png) is what it looks like.  I have these icons appear as non-stackable icons w/out text by using the taskbar property 'Taskbar buttons: Never Combine' and [this hack](http://www.windows7news.com/2009/08/26/add-never-combine-hide-labels-to-the-windows-7-taskbar/).

Anyone know how to fix this?  (I have the latest Windows updates installed-- this has been a problem for as long as I've been using Windows 7 -- about 2 years -- and it happens on 2 different laptops I own.)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Windows 7 x64 and my thin Taskbar ["ThinTask V2" or "Thinner Taskbar"], sided on the left: some icons dissapear by themselves and others when hovering over them [or the other way around]. Well, if we wan't to be more specific, the icons do not dissapear but get transparent ["empty"]

I did some research and came out of course empty handed; it seems yours discriprion of this problem is the only account of it on the Internet that I could find. The only solution that works for me is to make it by hand a little wider- but the drag is I have to do it every time I get into Windows